# AngularJS: make checkboxes with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to figure out why my list of checkboxes (from ng-repeat="song in myCtrl.genreSelected") is not showing properly

I have some radio boxes where you can select one of 3 music genres:

```
<input type="radio" name="genre" ng-value="myCtrl.rockSongs" ng-model="myCtrl.genreSelected"> Rock      
<input type="radio" name="genre" ng-value="myCtrl.rapSongs" ng-model="myCtrl.genreSelected"> Pop
<input type="radio" name="genre" ng-value="myCtrl.popSongs" ng-model="myCtrl.genreSelected"> Rap
```

And I want whichever radio is selected to create a list of checkboxes with the names of those songs:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="song" ng-repeat="song in myCtrl.genreSelected" ng-checked={{song.checked}}>{{song.song}}
```

Here are the songs in the controller for each genre:

```
this.rockSongs = [{song: "Rock song #1", checked: true},
                    {song: "Rock song #2", checked: false},
                    {song: "Rock song #3", checked: false},
                    {song: "Rock song #4", checked: false},
                    {song: "Rock song #5", checked: false}];

this.rapSongs = [{song: "Rap song #1", checked: false},
                {song: "Rap song #2", checked: false},
                {song: "Rap song #3", checked: false},
                {song: "Rap song #4", checked: false},
                {song: "Rap song #5", checked: false}];

this.popSongs = [{song: "Pop song #1", checked: false},
                {song: "Pop song #2", checked: false},
                {song: "Pop song #3", checked: false},
                {song: "Pop song #4", checked: false},
                {song: "Pop song #5", checked: false}];
```

Right now I have the rock songs to appearing on load:

```
this.genreSelected = this.rockSongs;
```

Right now the checkbox list appears from the ng-repeat with the check selected if checked: true.  But the name of the song does not appear where I have {{song.song}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two changes are needed.  First, use ng-model rather than ng-checked.  Second, in order to see the song names you'll need to wrap the input in a div and move the ng-repeat to the div.

```
<div ng-repeat="song in myCtrl.genreSelected">
   <input type="checkbox" name="song" ng-model='song.checked'>{{song.song}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The ngRepeat directive only repeats its element, so your `{{song.song}}` binding is actually outside of the ngRepeat.

You have to wrap the input and the binding in another element and repeat that instead

```
<div ng-repeat="song in myCtrl.genreSelected">
    <input type="checkbox" name="song" ng-checked="song.checked"> {{song.song}}
</div>
```

Or with two-way binding use ngModel:

```
<div ng-repeat="song in myCtrl.genreSelected">
    <input type="checkbox" name="song" ng-model="song.checked"> {{song.song}}
</div>
```